# Using @ViewScoped with master template doesn't reset inputs

Tags: jsf

I am using a master template (i.e. `<ui:composition template>` / `<ui:define>`) where I have a navigation panel on the left, and the content panel in the center.  When I go to one of my pages that is `@ViewScoped`, I edit some of the fields, go to another page which reloads the content area, and then go back to the original page, and the fields are all still populated with data.  This implies that the view never ended.  I tried `@RequestScoped` which produces the results I want, but breaks all of the ajax in the page related to that bean.

1. What is the best way to reset a page to its original state?
2. Can anyone see what is happening, exactly, regarding my layout and content area (consisting of a ui:include) being updated that would cause this not to be considered a change of View?

Comment: Are you navigating by ajax or so? I.e. you stay in the same view and only ajax-render some content? Best way would be to navigate by a normal request. This also instantly makes your pages bookmarkable and SEO-friendly.

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: Thanks so much for your response!

I'm using a p:submenu with p:menuitems in it and have an actionListener set on each which changes the view on the backing bean and udpates the content p:panel containing the ui:include.  I think ajax is used as I have not set that to false in any of the menuitems.

I am going to experiment with navigation by request.  I'm not exactly sure what options are out there, but I'm looking to find one that will only reload the content area, and retain the navigation pain (and the "north" header).  I'll get back to you soon.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, BalusC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By navigating the content of the page using a backing bean, a ui:include updated by ajax, all in the same page, JSF's current view never goes out of scope, which is why the backing ViewScoped beans are never reset after navigating.

One possible fix for this is to redesign the page to use traditional navigation.  In other words, lets say you have several p:menuitems.  Rather than assigning the actionListener to some backing bean function that sets the content page (followed by an update of the panel containing the ui:include), you would set the "action" of each menuitem to the page to which each corresponds.  This has the effect of causing a page to be loaded when a menuitem is clicked.

This generated the requirement that I had to reorganize my template a little so that every page of my site was embedded in it.  There's a little bit of flicker as the entire page reloads, but the beans are being reset accordingly.